# 1 Finger Right/Left Swipe on MAC OS X

Tags: cocoa, macos, swipe, trackpad, magic-mouse

I need to catch the event of one finger right/left swipe for the Magic Mouse or two finger swipe for the Trackpad.

So far I've managed to set the event for two finger swipe on the magic mouse/ three finger on the trackpad, but this won't work in MAC OS X Lion because as of this version, this swipe is set to navigate through spaces.

```
[NSEvent addLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask:NSEventMaskSwipe handler:^(NSEvent *event) {        
    if ([event deltaX] == 1.0) { //LEFT SWIPE
        [self backHistoryAction:nil];
    } else if ([event deltaX] == -1.0) { //RIGHT SWIPE
        [self forwardHistoryAction:nil];
    }        
    return event;
}];
```

Thanks in advance.

Mikywan.

Answer (score 0):

There’s a new API for swipes in Lion. See the [AppKit release notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Cocoa/AppKit.html).

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Kapeli/SwipableWebView/ is a WebView subclass that adds support for two-finger swipes (trackpad) and one-finger swipes (Magic Mouse). It should be trivial to port that code to support swipes in any other NSView.